# android studio: Symbol not found error

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am using Android studio on OSx 10.6.8.
When I run the app in emulator mode I get the following error

```
/Users/.../android-sdks/tools/emulator -avd AVD_for_Nexus_5_by_Google -netspeed full -netdelay none
dyld: Symbol not found: _NSWindowDidEnterFullScreenNotification
Referenced from: /Users/.../android-sdks/tools/emulator64-x86
Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit in /Users/.../android-sdks/tools/emulator64-x86
```

while there are no problem running on the real device.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Can you post your manifest and describe the application you are running.

Comment: The application is the default "Hello World" one.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it cropped up when I updated my SDK tools to version 24.1.2. [This thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77397) discusses the problem in more detail, but the gist is that the new SDK tools have OSX 10.8 as the minimum supported version.

I was running Android Studio on OSX 10.6.8 as you did and reinstalled the earlier version of the SDK tools (23.0.2) available [here](http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r23.0.2-macosx.zip). That did the trick and I have my AVD up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

**Three options**

In the SDK manager check you have the latest API version or at least the version you are targeting installed.

In the AVD create a new device edit your device with the CPU set to x86 instead of x86_64.

Go to file invalidate cache in androdi studio

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but none of them solved my problem